# Uninstallig 32 bit R Studio from 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: r, ubuntu-12.04, rstudio

When downloading R Studio on Ubuntu 12.04, I downloaded the 32 bit version instead of the 64 bit. Now I can't get the 64 bit version to download without removing the 32 version. But there's no reference to the 32 bit version (at least that I can find). What am I missing?

Comment: This should probably be posted on the Ubuntu site instead of here.

Comment: Here's the link, just in case http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge rstudio-server` ?